# Copy Large No. of log files from a shared folder in windows using scala code

Tags: java, scala, file, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to copy large amount of files (millions) from a network share to my pc using a scala code. The method I am using is listfiles() to get all the files in a folder and the go through the list to copy the files I want.It works fine for small no. of files, but as the no. of files becomes millions it throws memory out of bound exception. Is there any other method that I can use to iterate over the files and choose the one I want to copy which won't throw this exception in java or scala. I saw simple file visitor when I googled this issue, can anyone help me on how to use that for copying files after filtering from a folder.

```
def copyRenamedFiles(directoryName: String, trackerFileName: String, loggerFileName: String): Unit = {
    val destFolder = "D:\\data\\"
    val logWriter = Logger.getLogger("UploadServiceLog")
    logWriter.setUseParentHandlers(false)
    val hashMapForFileTracking = FileTracking.getTracker(trackerFileName, logWriter)
    try {
      println("Inside try block")
      //LogFile Informations........................
      val fh = new FileHandler(loggerFileName)
      logWriter.addHandler(fh)
      val formatter = new SimpleFormatter()
      fh.setFormatter(formatter)
      //............................................
      if (!new File(directoryName).exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Specified Path is not found")
      }
      val rootFile = new File(directoryName)
      println(rootFile.isDirectory)
      if (rootFile.isDirectory) {
        // println("Inside rootfolder\n"+rootFile.listFiles().length)
        rootFile.listFiles().foreach {
          machineFile => if (machineFile.isDirectory) {

            // My filter logic and copying goes here

}
```

But rootFile.listFiles (rootFile.list also) itself throws memory out of bound exception. The folder hierarchy is root folder -> many machine folders -> each machine folder contains many dailylogfolders -> each daily folder contains a log file.

Comment: Could you supply a code sample of what you're trying?

Comment: Normally one uses `rsync` (Linux tool, but probably on Windows too) or such; with compression and such. In your case check whether everything is closed too, also in case of exceptions; listFiles  may return a null `File[]`. Needs good error reporting (file in use, dynamic files).

Comment: @Conrad.Dean  I have added the code. can u see that ??

Comment: Doing twice listFiles and once list is costly. Check the recursion; listFiles is much data; collect its directories apart; maybe have a single todo list.

Comment: @JoopEggen I was using one listfiles only. the other one I added to check whether it is able to get atleast the file names as it returns an array of strings. But that also threw same exception

Comment: @JoopEggen Does listfiles pulls the data also or just a an array of file pointers?

Comment: Just an array of file paths, possibly null. The method `list()` giving only file names so being most compact. You might also want to try the newer replacement [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is that the array of files is too big to fit in memory, you should think how to get something that is evaluated lazily, a Stream or Iterator. Quick search, and I found this:

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/listing_directory_contents_with_jdk

This is copied from the link above

```
public static List<String> fileList(String directory) {
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(directory))) {
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            fileNames.add(path.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
    return fileNames;
}
```

it is a part of new java io library and shows how to create a DirectoryStream that should not take your whole memory.

Comment: Łukasz I had already tried this method earlier. Actually I want the code in scala. So when I tried this I couldnt complete since i couldnt apply filter over directory stream. Now noticed that I can apply iterator over the stream. So I think it will work. Thanks for ur time

Comment: DirectoryStream implements java Iterable, you can convert it to scala Iterable and have all methods.

Comment: Yeah could finish it using iterator. thanks again for ur help